# Spring Authentication Manager

Tags: spring-security

I am new to Spring Security as per my Knowledge authentication manager in spring checks all the authentication provider sequentially. I just want to know wether we can decide sequence of authentication provider on run time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to my own question .

we can implement the authentication manager interface and write number of conditions and thus decide the sequence of authentication providers.

Answer (score 0):

`AuthenticationManger` is an interface, so it can be implemented any way you want. The default implementation has a list of `AuthenticationProvider` instances and checks them in sequence. So you control the sequence by the order in which you add them to the configuration.

Comment: So there is no chance for me to decide it on runtime right ?

Comment: You could do it by changing the ordering of the list, but why would you want to change it at runtime?

Comment: According to our Functional Requirement, I need to change the sequence dynamically. So Can you please give me some solution on this